# Determining when was the last time a plugin was activated

Tags: plugins

I'm currently doing an audit on a WordPress site for some supervisors and was curious if there was any way under the hood to see when was the last time a plugin was actually activated.  This will give me some leverage in removing them if its been a while.  Is there anyway I can complete this type of investigation through WordPress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like, in a Multisite installation, any network-wide plugins record their activation time in a site option. By default, plugins activated in a single site in a Multisite network (or in a single-site installation) do not.

See [the source of the `activate_plugin()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/activate_plugin/).

You *could* write a simple plugin that records that information, using the [`activated_plugin` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/activated_plugin/), but that won't help you with any older plugins -- any data you record that way would only exist from now[^1] on out.

[^1]: If by "now" we mean "the moment you activate your plugin-tracking plugin".

Comment: Love it, I may actually look into building this, and if successful see what life brings for plugin usage on our end in the next 3 to 6 months.  Many thanks!